# How can Docker on Windows 10 access Network Drives?

Tags: docker, windows-10

I wrote some scripts I use in a docker container. For the scripts to be usefull I need to access some network mounts.

On my Mac it's easy. In my docker-compose.yml I have:

```
volumes:
- type: bind
  source: /Volumes/Teams/myteam/folder/subfolder
  target: /subfolder
```

On my colleagues Windows Laptop `/Volumes/Teams` is mounted as `T:` so my naive approach was to use

```
volumes:
- type: bind
  source: /t/myteam/folder/subfolder
  target: /subfolder
```

From the git shell this path can be used. But when starting `docker-compose up` from that shell, he gets error messages

```
ERROR: for 255d3d7d2944_my-tools_helpscripts_1  Cannot create container for service helpscripts: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "T:/myteam/folder/subfolder"\ndoesn\'t exist and is not known to Docker'

Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

In docker's settings for shared drives, the `T:` drive is not listed.

How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Add them to source control and `COPY` them into your image.  That will make the image self-contained and you won't have to worry about mounting extra content in to make the container useful.  This is doubly important if you move to a clustered environment like Kubernetes, where you'd also have to make sure every node had the same mount configuration; it's better to just keep everything you need in the image itself.

Comment: Nice idea, @DavidMaze, but that's not feasible as the (currently) 629MB data on the share changes. Sure my colleague could build a new image every time he needs the scripts, but what about the data the scripts change in the share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution that should fit for me:

1. Start my container with capabilities  `SYS_ADMIN` and `DAC_READ_SEARCH`
2. Mount inside the containter with
   `mount -t cifs -o user=USER,domain=DOMAIN //SERVER/Teams /mnt/T`